# Scikit-learn bad input shape () for a particular column

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to run a kNN classifier on the Seismic Bumps [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00266/seismic-bumps.arff) but when I try to encode the labels for the shift attribute I get bad value error. Here is the code:

```
col_names = ['seismic', 'seismoacoustic', 'shift', 
         'genergy', 'gpuls', 'gdenergy', 'gdpuls',
         'ghazard', 'nbumps', 'nbumps2', 'nbumps3',
         'nbumps4', 'nbumps5', 'nbumps6', 'nbumps7',
         'nbumps89', 'energy', 'maxenergy', 'class']

# Import
sbumps_ds = pd.read_csv('SeismicBumpsDataset.csv', names = col_names)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelenc = LabelEncoder()

# Encode class names to numbers
#sbumps_ds['seismic'] = labelenc.fit_transform(sbumps_ds.seismic)
#sbumps_ds['seismoacoustic'] = labelenc.fit_transform(sbumps_ds.seismoacoustic)
sbumps_ds['shift'] = labelenc.fit_transform(sbumps_ds.shift)
#sbumps_ds['ghazard'] = labelenc.fit_transform(sbumps_ds.ghazard)
#sbumps_ds['shift'] = sbumps_ds.shift.map({'W' : 0, 'N' : 1})
#sbumps_ds['seismic'] = sbumps_ds.seismic.map({'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd': 3})
```

The shapes of all the attributes are equal.
Here is the error:

```
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Also, when I try to map the attribute values, I get this error:

```
sbumps_ds['shift'] = sbumps_ds.shift.map({'W' : 0, 'N' : 1})
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'map'
```

The error is raised **only** for that attribute. If I change the name of shift, the classifier works.

Comment: DataFrames have a [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method

Comment: My google skills suck I guess... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to `sbumps_ds['shift'].map(...)`.

`sbumpt_ds.shift` is a method of dataframes, so it returns that function rather than the column named `"shift"`.